# Bash simple script copying files to specific folder + renaming to todays effective date

Tags: bash, shell, automation

Good day, 
I need your help in creating next script
Every day teacher uploading files in next format:

```
STUDENT_ACCOUNTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
STUDENT_MARKS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
STUNDENT_HOMEWORKS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
STUDENT_PHYSICAL_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx
```

**[file_name+todaydatetime-todaydate.xlsx]**

But sometimes a teacher is not uploading these files and we need to do manual renaming the files received for the previous date and then copying every separate file to separate folder like:

```
cp STUDENT_ACCOUNTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx /incoming/A1/STUDENT_ACCOUNTS_20200318074343-20200318.xlsx  
cp STUDENT_MARKS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  /incoming/B1/STUDENT_ACCOUNTS_20200318074343-20200318.xlsx  
.............

cp SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx /incoming/F1/SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200318074343-20200318.xlsx.
```

In two words - taking the files from previous date copying them to specific folder with a new timestamp.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/incoming/
date=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
previousdate="$( date --date=yesterday '+%Y%m%d' )"
cp /home/incoming/SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_'$previousdate'.xlsx /incoming/F1/SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_'$date'.xlsx
```

and there could be case when teacher can upload one file and others not, how to do check for existing files? 
Thanks for reading that, if you can help me i will ne really thankful - you will save plenty of manual work for me.

Comment: Why is `previousdate` just today with hyphens? I think maybe you wanted `previousdate="$( date --date=yesterday '+%Y%m%d' )"`

Comment: thanks you are right

Comment: Try `for i in  /home/incoming/SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_*; do echo $i; done`

Comment: You can use `for` loop for repetition of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The process can be automated completely if your directory structure is known. If it follows some kind of pattern, do mention it here.

For the timing, this maybe helpful:

Filename "tscp"

```
#
# Stands for timestamped cp
#
tscp() {

    local file1=$1 ; shift
    local to_dir=$1 ; shift
    local force_copy=$1 ; shift

    local current_date="$(date '+%Y%m%d')"

    if [ "${force_copy}" == "--force" ] ; then
        cp "${file1}" "${to_dir}/$(basename ${file1%-*})-${current_date}.xlsx"
    else
        cp -n "${file1}" "${to_dir}/$( basename ${file1%-*})-${current_date}.xlsx"
    fi
}

tscp "$@"
```

It's usage is as follows:

```
tscp source to_directory [-—force]
```

Basically the script takes 2 arguments and the 3rd one is optional.

First arg is source file path and second are is the directory path to where you want to copy (`.` if same directory).

By default this copy would be made if and only if destination file doesn't exist.

If you want to overwrite the destination file then pass a third arg `—force`.

Again, this can be refined much much more based on details provided.

Sample usage for now:

```
bash tscp SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx /incoming/F1/
```

will copy SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx to directory /incoming/F1/ with updated date if it doesn't exist yet.

## UPDATE:

Give this a go:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

printf_err() {
    ERR_COLOR='\033[0;31m'
    NORMAL_COLOR='\033[0m'
    printf "${ERR_COLOR}$1${NORMAL_COLOR}" ; shift
    printf "${ERR_COLOR}%s${NORMAL_COLOR}\n" "$@" >&2
}

alias printf_err='printf_err "Line ${LINENO}: " '
shopt -s expand_aliases

usage() {

    printf_err \
        "" \
        "usage: ${BASH_SOURCE##*/} " \
        "  -f copy_data_file" \
        "  -d days_before" \
        "  -m months_before" \
        "  -o" \
        "  -y years_before" \
        "  -r " \
        "  -t to_dir" \
            >&2

    exit 1
}

fullpath() {
    local path="$1" ; shift
    local abs_path

    if [ -z "${path}" ] ; then
        printf_err "${BASH_SOURCE}: Line ${LINENO}: param1(path) is empty"
        return 1
    fi

    abs_path="$( cd "$( dirname "${path}" )" ; pwd )/$( basename ${path} )"

    printf "${abs_path}"
}

OVERWRITE=0
REVIEW=0
COPYSCRIPT="$( mktemp "/tmp/copyscriptXXXXX" )"

while getopts 'f:d:m:y:t:or' option
do
    case "${option}" in
        d)
            DAYS="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        f)
            INPUT_FILE="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        m)
            MONTHS="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        t)
            TO_DIR="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        y)
            YEARS="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        o)
            OVERWRITE=1
            ;;
        r)
            REVIEW=1
            COPYSCRIPT="copyscript"
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done

INPUT_FILE=${INPUT_FILE:-$1}
TO_DIR=${TO_DIR:-$2}

if [ ! -f "${INPUT_FILE}" ] ; then
    printf_err "No such file ${INPUT_FILE}"
    usage
fi


DAYS="${DAYS:-1}"
MONTHS="${MONTHS:-0}"
YEARS="${YEARS:-0}"

if date -v -1d > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # BSD date

    previous_date="$( date -v -${DAYS}d -v -${MONTHS}m -v -${YEARS}y '+%Y%m%d' )"

else
    # GNU date

    previous_date="$( date --date="-${DAYS} days -${MONTHS} months -${YEARS} years" '+%Y%m%d' )"

fi

current_date="$( date '+%Y%m%d' )"

tmpfile="$( mktemp "/tmp/dstnamesXXXXX" )"


awk -v to_replace="${previous_date}" -v replaced="${current_date}" '{

    gsub(to_replace, replaced, $0)
    print

}' ${INPUT_FILE} > "${tmpfile}"


paste ${INPUT_FILE} "${tmpfile}" |
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a arr
    do
        src=${arr[0]}
        dst=${arr[1]}
        opt=${arr[2]}

        if [ -n "${opt}" ] ; then

            if [ ! -d "${dst}" ] ;
            then
                printf_err "No such directory ${dst}"
                usage
            fi

            dst="${dst}/$( basename "${opt}" )"

        else

            if [ ! -d "${TO_DIR}" ] ; 
            then
                printf_err "No such directory ${TO_DIR}"
                usage
            fi

            dst="${TO_DIR}/$( basename "${dst}" )"
        fi

        src=$( fullpath "${src}" )
        dst=$( fullpath "${dst}" )

        if [ -n "${OVERWRITE}" ] ; then
            echo "cp ${src} ${dst}"
        else
            echo "cp -n ${src} ${dst}"
        fi
    done > "${COPYSCRIPT}"


if [ "${REVIEW}" -eq 0 ] ; then

    ${BASH} "${COPYSCRIPT}"
    rm "${COPYSCRIPT}"

fi

rm "${tmpfile}"
```

### Steps:

1. Store the above script in a file, say `tscp`.
2. Now you need to create the input file for it.

   From you example, a sample input file can be like:

   ```
   STUDENT_ACCOUNTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx         /incoming/A1/
   STUDENT_MARKS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx         /incoming/B1/
   STUNDENT_HOMEWORKS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
   STUDENT_PHYSICAL_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
   SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx         /incoming/FI/
   ```

   Where first part is the source file name and after a "tab" (it should be a tab for sure), you mention the destination directory. These paths should be either absolute or relative the the directory where you are executing the script.
    You may not mention destination directory if all are to be sent to same directory (discussed later).

   Let's say you named this file `file`.

   Also, you don't really have to type all that. If you have these files in the current directory, just do this:

   ```
   ls -1 > file
   ```

   (the above is ls "one", not "l".)
3. Now we have the `file` from above in which we didn't mention destination directory for all but only for some.
   Let's say we want to move all other directories to `/incoming/x` and it exists.

   Now script is to be executed like:

   ```
   bash tscp -f file -t /incoming/x -r
   ```

   Where `/incoming/x` is the default directory i.e. when none other directory is mentioned in `file`, your files are moved to this directory.

   Now in the current directory a script named `copyscript` will be generated which will contain `cp` commands to copy all files. You can open a review `copyscript` and if the copying seems right, go ahead and:

   ```
   bash copyscript
   ```

   which will copy all the files and then you can:

   ```
   rm copyscript
   ```
4. You need not generate to `copyscript` and can straight away go for a copy like:

   ```
   bash tscp -f file -t /incoming/x
   ```

   which won't generate any copyscript and copy straight away.


   Previously `-r` caused the generation of `copyscript`.
   I would recomment to use version with `-r` because that is a little safer and you will be sure that right copies are being made.
5. By default it would check for the previous day and rename to current date, but you can override that behaviour as:

   ```
   bash tscp -f file -t /incoming/x -d 3
   ```

   `-d 3` would look for 3 days back files in `file`.
6. By default copies won't overwrite i.e. if file at the destination already exists, copies won't be made.
   If you want to overwrite, add flag `-o`.

As a conclusion I would advice to use:

```
bash tscp -f file -r
```

where `file` contains tab separated values like above for all.

Also, adding `tscp` to path would be a good idea after you are sure it works ok.

Also the scipt is made on `mac` and there is always a change of version clash of tools used. I would suggest to try the script on some sample data first to make sure script works right on your machine.

Comment: THANKS FOR HELPING ME, can I put in script already predefined file names which i know will be in incoming folder? like :``` file1=STUDENT_MARKS_[previousdatetime].xlsx file2= STUDENT_ACCOUNTS_[Previousdatetime].xlsx -> copy file1 to /incoming/F1-[todaydate]/STUDENT_MARKS_[todaydate].xlsx and file2 to /incoming/A1-[todaydate]/STUDENT_ACCOUNTS[todaydate].xlsx .``` sorry for asking stupid questions, there like 15 files which should use such workflow and of course checkup if , for example, file1=/incoming/F1-[todaydate]/STUDENT_MARKS_[todaydate] already existing. If you have paypal please share :)

Comment: @Kwaker, you can hardcode the names into the script but I won't really suggest you to do that. Instead you can have a textfile with all filenames in it through which the script can loop and do the task. A simple utility for this purpose can be designed.  Just like you use `cp` command. You can have your own version `cp` with custom options to make your life easier. Like you could have  `cp —date-rename <src_file> <dst_file>` or `cp —file <textfile>`(for renaming all files mentioned in a timestamped way). Will that do good? ...contd in next comment…..

Comment: contd...If that sounds good I will update the answer to reflect the changes and wlll provide the instructions to make it simple to use. You can update the question if you have any more requirements from the utility. As for the paypal thing, I really appreciate the gratitude but answering here is just my hobby and nevertheless I will update the answer till your query is solved.

Comment: Yeah and different files are going to different folder so I was thikibg to hardcode it as well. I think what is an easier way for you is better solution thanks again

Comment: @Kwaker, I will update the answer by night when I reach home.

Comment: thousand thanks, take your time - your script will save hours of my manual work!

Comment: @Kwaker, updated the answer. Give it a try on some sample data and lemme know if it works on your machine.

Comment: i definetly should somehow to repay you for that , i didnt expect it will be such a titanic labor to do it. I'm finishing tasks for today and during lunch will try it! 100000 thanks

Comment: one stupid question - what to do if i need to put files:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209991/discussion-between-mihir-and-kwaker).